# Import Jenkins job definition into TFS 2017

Tags: jenkins, build-definition

Is it possible, or are there tools available to allow you, to import or convert a legacy Jenkins job build definition into a TFS 2017 build definition.  I'm not looking to convert the job to a Jenkins job within TFS, but simply use the steps contained in the Jenkins job to create a new build definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the steps contained in jenkins job you are meaning  just as the following screen shows which you can specify the details of the job.

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not able to directly covert this to a TFS build definition. There is no such kind tool could do this. It's only able to Export/Import TFS vNext Build Definition itself. You have to manually convert jenkins job build definition to TFS build definition.